# Complexity in distributed system

Tags: distributed-computing, bit

if I have a network of n nodes with unique id's chosen from a range say 1 to n squared, then order of log n bits are sufficient and also necessary to address the nodes in the network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume each node is given an ID in *[1, n<sup>2</sup>]*, and that we have no control over the assignment of IDs. You agree that if we can encode any such ID in *Θ(log n)* bits, then your statement of sufficiency also follows.

Now, any integer *x* requires *Θ(log x)* bits in binary. Thus, writing our maximum integer *n<sup>2</sup>* in binary requires *Θ(log n<sup>2</sup>)* bits. We notice that:

*Θ(log n<sup>2</sup>)*

= *Θ(2 log n)*           | properties of logarithms

= *Θ(log n)*              | properties of *Θ*

This shows the sufficiency. As for necessity, it follows more trivially from the properties of [numeral systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeral_system).